# Set up routing pages for next-connect

Tags: node.js, next.js, next-connect

I set up a server with **next-connect**. Now how can I move requests to the **pages** folder of my **nextjs** program?
This is my server js file:

```
const nc = require("next-connect");

const {auth} = require("../app/middlewares/auth");

const handler = nc()
.use(auth)
.get((req, res) => {
console.log('->', req.session.get('user'))
// Render the requested page from the pages folder
}).post();

createServer(handler).listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you created a custom backend for your Next.js project probably using Node.js and express. This requires some critical changes throughout the project.

You can read the documentation here. https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server

Comment: Thanks. I solved my problem by adding express to my web application, as well as using the nextjs project management structure.